# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, commonjs, rollupjs

Following are the steps I do to generate **bundle.min.js**:

1) firstly, tscompile with **es2015** for my target and module.

2) npm run rollup (*i.e., rollup -f iife -c -o dist/prod/client/app/bundle.es2015.js*).

3) npm run es5 (i.e., *tsc --target es5 --allowJs dist/prod/client/app/bundle.es2015.js --out dist/prod/client/app/bundle.js*).

4) npm run minify (*i.e., uglifyjs dist/prod/client/app/bundle.js --screw-ie8 --compress --mangle --output dist/prod/client/app/**bundle.min.js*** ).

**Below is the error after minification:**

> Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected strict mode reserved word SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected strict mode reserved word at ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:203:28) at Zone.run
>   (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:96:43) at
>   https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:462:57 at
>   ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:236:37) at Zone.runTask
>   (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:136:47) at
>   drainMicroTaskQueue
>   (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.25?main=browser:368:35) Evaluating
>   http://localhost:9000/app/bundle.min.js Error loading
>   http://localhost:9000/app/bundle.min.js

[image]

I'm getting above error while I'm creating the **production** build for my angular2 application using Rollup.js for Tree Shaking but I'm not sure what im doing wrong earlier it was working fine and still its working on **development** environment but not in production kindly help me I've also tried to run my app without minification **i.e., 4th step** **and it shows  below error:**

> Error: TypeError: __extends is not a function ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this mentioned a few times, as far as I know the fix is to upgrade your node stuff (what version of Node/npm are you running).

If you've tried that and it's the same problem, then I'd go back to the original error, which is that somewhere you are using a reserved keyword (like yield or some such) as a var name, and you're not supposed to be doing that.

Comment: node version => v6.2.2  
npm version => 3.10.5
@TimConsolazio

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'use strict' if in case you are using.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7969